# Render whole page HTML in a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I've a URL (http://www.basic-slider.com/) that contains a slider. What I want is to get the whole page content in a javascript variable by escaping it and then place this content in my empty body tag through innerHTML or jQuery .html function.

The code is simply being put in the body tag but its not working like original page. I've to show it exactly same as original page.

I can't use iframe or any XMLHTTP method. Here is the code for the above corresponding URL:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="mustache.js"></script>
<script>
var strVar="";
strVar += "<!DOCTYPE html>";
strVar += "<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class=\"no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7\"> <![endif]-->";
strVar += "<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class=\"no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8\"> <![endif]-->";
strVar += "<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class=\"no-js lt-ie9\"> <![endif]-->";
strVar += "<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class=\"no-js\"> <!--<![endif]-->";
strVar += " <head>";
strVar += "     <meta charset=\"utf-8\">";
strVar += "     <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge,chrome=1\">";
strVar += "     <title>Basic jQuery Slider - Responsive slideshows for featured content<\/title>";
strVar += "     <meta name=\"description\" content=\"A simple, no-frills, robust jQuery plugin for creating simple, responsive slideshows for your featured content. Simple to use, theme and customise.\">";
strVar += "     <link href='http:\/\/fonts.googleapis.com\/css?family=Source+Code+Pro|Coda|Open+Sans:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text\/css'>";
strVar += "     <link href=\"\/\/maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com\/font-awesome\/4.1.0\/css\/font-awesome.min.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">";
strVar += "     <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css\/bootstrap.min.css\">";
strVar += "     <style>";
strVar += "         body {";
strVar += "             padding-top: 60px;";
strVar += "             padding-bottom: 40px;";
strVar += "         }";
strVar += "     <\/style>";
strVar += "     <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://www.basic-slider.com\/css\/main.css\">";
strVar += "     <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"http://www.basic-slider.com\/css\/prism.css\">";
strVar += "";
strVar += "     <script src=\"http://www.basic-slider.com\/js\/vendor\/modernizr-2.6.1-respond-1.1.0.min.js\"><\/script>";
strVar += " <\/head>";
strVar += " <body>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "     <div class=\"container\">";
strVar += "         <div class=\"row\">";
strVar += "             <header class=\"span12\">";
strVar += "                 <h1>Basic jQuery Slider<\/h1>";
strVar += "                 <h2>Simple to use, simple to theme, simple to customise<\/h2>";
strVar += "             <\/header>";
strVar += "             <div class=\"span12\" id=\"slider\">";
strVar += "                 <ul class=\"bjqs\">";
strVar += "                 <li><img src=\"img\/banner01.jpg\" title=\"Automatically generated caption\"><\/li>";
strVar += "                 <li><img src=\"img\/banner02.jpg\" title=\"Automatically generated caption\"><\/li>";
strVar += "                 <li><img src=\"img\/banner03.jpg\" title=\"Automatically generated caption\"><\/li>";
strVar += "                 <\/ul>";
strVar += "             <\/div>";
strVar += "<div class=\"span12 leaderboard-ad\">";
strVar += "<script async src=\"\/\/pagead2.googlesyndication.com\/pagead\/js\/adsbygoogle.js\"><\/script>";
strVar += "<!-- Leaderboard -->";
strVar += "<ins class=\"adsbygoogle\"";
strVar += " style=\"display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px\"";
strVar += " data-ad-client=\"ca-pub-7070404889996835\"";
strVar += " data-ad-slot=\"7960663502\"><\/ins>";
strVar += "<script>";
strVar += "(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});";
strVar += "<\/script>";
strVar += "<\/div>";
strVar += "             <div class=\"span12 text\">";
strVar += "                 <h3>Purpose<\/h3>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <p>There are a lot of jQuery content sliders out there. Most of them are loaded with cool features and skins, which are great if it is exactly what you are looking for, but more often than not you need to customise it for your own needs and it can be difficult cutting through the bloat of a full featured slider.<\/p>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <p>Basic jQuery Slider has been developed to be as simple and lightweight as possible. Only the essential functionality has been included combined with clean semantic mark-up. This means instead of removing features and bending it to suit your needs, you can use this slider and as a base and with a little bit of CSS and JavaScript knowledge, you can extend it to be as feature rich, or as simple, as you need.<\/p>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                     <h3>Download<\/h3>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <section class=\"clearfix\">";
strVar += "                     <div class=\"download\">";
strVar += "                         <p>You can download the plugin for free, however if you'd like to support the ongoing hosting and development of the plugin, you can optionally purchase it for $3 - the cost of your morning coffee :)<\/p>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                         <div class=\"buttons\">";
strVar += "                             <a class=\"btn btn-success\" style=\"font-size: 20px; padding: 20px;\" href=\"https:\/\/gumroad.com\/l\/XsbID\"><i class=\"fa fa-smile-o\"><\/i> Download with donation<\/a>";
strVar += "                             <a style=\"display: block; padding: 20px; text-align: center;\" href=\"http:\/\/github.com\/jcobb\/basic-jquery-slider\/\"><i class=\"icon-download-alt icon-white\"><\/i> Download for Free<\/a>";
strVar += "                         <\/div>";
strVar += "                     <\/div>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <div class=\"ad-space\">";
strVar += "";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                     ";
strVar += "<script async src=\"\/\/pagead2.googlesyndication.com\/pagead\/js\/adsbygoogle.js\"><\/script>";
strVar += "<!-- LREC -->";
strVar += "<ins class=\"adsbygoogle\"";
strVar += " style=\"display:inline-block;width:336px;height:280px\"";
strVar += " data-ad-client=\"ca-pub-7070404889996835\"";
strVar += " data-ad-slot=\"2053730701\"><\/ins>";
strVar += "<script>";
strVar += "(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});";
strVar += "<\/script>";
strVar += "                 <\/div>";
strVar += "                 <\/section>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <h3 style=\"clearfix\">Usage<\/h3>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <h5>Plugin dependancies<\/h5>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <p>There are two core files required to get up and running with Basic jQuery Slider, the JavaScript plugin and the base css.  The only dependancy is jQuery, so you will also need to make sure you have the latest version of the jQuery library included in your page. <\/p>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <pre><code class=\"language-markup\">&lt;!-- Include the jQuery library (local or CDN) --&gt;";
strVar += "&lt;script src=\"http:\/\/code.jquery.com\/jquery-latest.min.js\"&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;";
strVar += "";
strVar += "&lt;!-- Include the plugin *after* the jQuery library --&gt;";
strVar += "&lt;script src=\"bjqs.min.js\"&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;";
strVar += "";
strVar += "&lt;!-- Include the basic styles --&gt;";
strVar += "&lt;link type=\"text\/css\" rel=\"Stylesheet\" href=\"bjqs.css\" \/&gt;<\/code><\/pre>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <h5>Markup<\/h5>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <p>The basic markup for the plugin is as follows.<\/p>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <ul>";
strVar += "                     <li>An outer container which the plugin will be attached to,<\/li>";
strVar += "                     <li>An unordered list element with a class name of bjqs, and<\/li>";
strVar += "                     <li>Individual list elements for each slide.<\/li>";
strVar += "                 <\/ul>";
strVar += "<pre><code class=\"language-markup\">&lt;div id=\"my-slideshow\"&gt;";
strVar += " &lt;ul class=\"bjqs\"&gt;";
strVar += "     &lt;li&gt;&lt;!-- Any content you like --&gt;&lt;\/li&gt;";
strVar += "     &lt;li&gt;&lt;!-- Can go inside these slides--&gt;&lt;\/li&gt;";
strVar += " &lt;\/ul&gt;";
strVar += "&lt;\/div&gt;<\/code><\/pre>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <h5>Activation<\/h5>";
strVar += "                 <p>The final step is to invoke the plugin and attach it to the outer-most dom element. You can then pass in a variety of key : value pairs to configure the slider.<\/p>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "<pre><code class=\"language-javascript\">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {";
strVar += " $('#banner-fade').bjqs({";
strVar += "     'height' : 320,";
strVar += "     'width' : 620,";
strVar += "     'responsive' : true";
strVar += " });";
strVar += "});";
strVar += "<\/code><\/pre>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "<div class=\"span12 leaderboard-ad\">";
strVar += "<script async src=\"\/\/pagead2.googlesyndication.com\/pagead\/js\/adsbygoogle.js\"><\/script>";
strVar += "<!-- Leaderboard Bottom -->";
strVar += "<ins class=\"adsbygoogle\"";
strVar += " style=\"display:inline-block;width:728px;height:90px\"";
strVar += " data-ad-client=\"ca-pub-7070404889996835\"";
strVar += " data-ad-slot=\"3251262300\"><\/ins>";
strVar += "<script>";
strVar += "(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});";
strVar += "<\/script>";
strVar += "<\/div>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <h3>Options<\/h3>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "                 <p>Here is a full list of all the possible parameters which can used to configure the plugin and their default values.<\/p>";
strVar += "                 <pre><code class=\"language-javascript\">\/\/ width and height need to be provided to enforce consistency";
strVar += "\/\/ if responsive is set to true, these values act as maximum dimensions";
strVar += "width : 700,";
strVar += "height : 300,";
strVar += "";
strVar += "\/\/ animation values";
strVar += "animtype : 'fade', \/\/ accepts 'fade' or 'slide'";
strVar += "animduration : 450, \/\/ how fast the animation are";
strVar += "animspeed : 4000, \/\/ the delay between each slide";
strVar += "automatic : true, \/\/ automatic";
strVar += "";
strVar += "\/\/ control and marker configuration";
strVar += "showcontrols : true, \/\/ show next and prev controls";
strVar += "centercontrols : true, \/\/ center controls verically";
strVar += "nexttext : 'Next', \/\/ Text for 'next' button (can use HTML)";
strVar += "prevtext : 'Prev', \/\/ Text for 'previous' button (can use HTML)";
strVar += "showmarkers : true, \/\/ Show individual slide markers";
strVar += "centermarkers : true, \/\/ Center markers horizontally";
strVar += "";
strVar += "\/\/ interaction values";
strVar += "keyboardnav : true, \/\/ enable keyboard navigation";
strVar += "hoverpause : true, \/\/ pause the slider on hover";
strVar += "";
strVar += "\/\/ presentational options";
strVar += "usecaptions : true, \/\/ show captions for images using the image title tag";
strVar += "randomstart : true, \/\/ start slider at random slide";
strVar += "responsive : true \/\/ enable responsive capabilities (beta)<\/code><\/pre>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "             <\/div>";
strVar += "         <\/div>";
strVar += "     <\/div>";
strVar += " ";
strVar += "";
strVar += "     <script src=\"\/\/ajax.googleapis.com\/ajax\/libs\/jquery\/1.8.2\/jquery.min.js\"><\/script>";
strVar += "     <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src=\"http://www.basic-slider.com\/js\/vendor\/jquery-1.8.2.min.js\"><\\/script>')<\/script>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "     <script src=\"http://www.basic-slider.com\/js\/vendor\/bootstrap.min.js\"><\/script>";
strVar += "     <script src=\"http://www.basic-slider.com\/js\/bjqs-1.3.min.js\"><\/script>";
strVar += "     <script src=\"http://www.basic-slider.com\/js\/main.js\"><\/script>";
strVar += "             <script src=\"http://www.basic-slider.com\/js\/vendor\/prism.js\"><\/script>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "<!-- TEH GOOGLES -->";
strVar += "<script type=\"text\/javascript\">";
strVar += "";
strVar += " var _gaq = _gaq || [];";
strVar += " _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-25642114-1']);";
strVar += " _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);";
strVar += "";
strVar += " (function() {";
strVar += " var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text\/javascript'; ga.async = true;";
strVar += " ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https:\/\/ssl' : 'http:\/\/www') + '.google-analytics.com\/ga.js';";
strVar += " var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);";
strVar += " })();";
strVar += "";
strVar += "<\/script>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "<!-- Woopra -->";
strVar += "<script type=\"text\/javascript\">";
strVar += " function woopraReady(tracker) {";
strVar += " tracker.setDomain('basic-slider.com');";
strVar += " tracker.setIdleTimeout(300000);";
strVar += " tracker.track();";
strVar += " return false;";
strVar += " }";
strVar += " (function() {";
strVar += "     var wsc = document.createElement('script');";
strVar += "     wsc.src = document.location.protocol+'\/\/static.woopra.com\/js\/woopra.js';";
strVar += "     wsc.type = 'text\/javascript';";
strVar += "     wsc.async = true;";
strVar += "     var ssc = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];";
strVar += "     ssc.parentNode.insertBefore(wsc, ssc);";
strVar += " })();";
strVar += "<\/script>";
strVar += "";
strVar += "<!-- Gauges -->";
strVar += "<script type=\"text\/javascript\">";
strVar += " var _gauges = _gauges || [];";
strVar += " (function() {";
strVar += "     var t   = document.createElement('script');";
strVar += "     t.type  = 'text\/javascript';";
strVar += "     t.async = true;";
strVar += "     t.id    = 'gauges-tracker';";
strVar += "     t.setAttribute('data-site-id', '4f471b24f5a1f55972000042');";
strVar += "     t.src = '\/\/secure.gaug.es\/track.js';";
strVar += "     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];";
strVar += "     s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s);";
strVar += " })();";
strVar += "<\/script>";
strVar += " <\/body>";
strVar += "<\/html>";

$(document).ready(function(){
    var newhtml = $.parseHTML(strVar);
    document.getElementById('body').innerHTML += strVar;

    //eval($('#body').find('script').text());
});

</script>
</head>
<body id="body">

</body>
</html>
```

Could anybody please tell me the solution to make it work exactly like original page. Don't worry about the css paths and JS paths. They will be absolute in my case.

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to render an entire website in a div..?

Comment: Because I've to show some contents of a web page offline in my smart tv application

Comment: But why do you need that javascript? Why can't you just put the html in the html-file?

Comment: `html` and `head` elements cannot go inside `body`.

Comment: Make a div, and try to append the content as a string to the div

Comment: And yes, as kos mentioned, you can't add html and head tags inside body

Comment: The problem is only with javascript code. The javascript in given string is not called properly

Comment: The javascript tags included in head are not executed. How to execute them

Comment: @ManishJangir can you not have the required js and css files locally, and then call them from within the JS frame from a local source instead? If your only issue is having head and html elements inside of the body, why not eliminate them entirely and invoke them elsewhere?

Comment: Granted my suggestion is theory based, can't say I've ever attempted to do what you're trying to achieve but that sounds like it should work, assuming there arent any scope issues.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `iframe` inside the `div` and set the contents of that `iframe`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var newhtml = $.parseHTML(strVar);
    document.getElementById('body').innerHTML += "<iframe id='ifr1'></iframe>";
    document.getElementById('ifr').src = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + escape(strVar);
});
```

Comment: @ManishJangir any specific reason why you can't use iframe?

Comment: Because the application will be run in samsung smart tv and that doesn't allow to use iframe

Comment: @ManishJangir Then try using frame rather than iframe.  Your smart tv should be able to handle frames (in case it can't handle iframe, which i doubt)